# php help cannot get code to loop in xml file to wight to database

Tags: php, database, simplexml

i have put this code in  i get all the right products_id but all the products_model are the same number

```
 foreach($xml->xpath('//PRODUCT/@ITEM') as $productitemid){
 foreach($xml->CREATED->CATEGORY->PRODUCT as $product)

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (products_id,products_model) VALUES ('$productitemid','$product->MODEL')");

}
```

Comment: Can we see how the XML is formatted? Thanks.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<STOREITEMS>
<CREATED value="Fri Feb 22 1:01:02 GMT 2013">
<CATEGORY id="442" name=" > test">
<PRODUCT ITEM="12796">
<NAME>Furry test</NAME>
<MODEL>bb2018</MODEL>
<PRICE>2.28</PRICE>
<RRP>3.99</RRP>
<THUMB>bb2018s.jpg</THUMB>
<IMAGE>bb2018.jpg</IMAGE>
<DESCRIPTION>

Comment: It would be even more helpful if you would edit your initial post, since you can't format code in comments...

Comment: these are at the end file </DESCRIPTION>
</PRODUCT>
</CATEGORY>
</CREATED>
</STOREITEMS>

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple 'product' items in your input file, then you need to iterate through them. You 'foreach' needs to look look something like this:

```
foreach($xml->CREATED->CATEGORY->PRODUCT as $product)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (products_model) VALUES ('$product->model')")
```

Notice that the problem is that your code `$xml->CREATED->CATEGORY->PRODUCT->MODEL` means "get me the 'MODEL' elements from the first 'PRODUCT' element. So that's why you only get one item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have put in code like you now i get all the right products_id but all the products_model are the same number
 
foreach($xml->xpath('//PRODUCT/@ITEM') as $productitemid){
 foreach($xml->CREATED->CATEGORY->PRODUCT as $product)
 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (products_id,products_model) VALUES ('$productitemid','$product->MODEL')");
 
}

Comment: You need to think about what exactly is being looped over in each of your `foreach` statements - your latest code has an outer foreach looking at `$xml->xpath('//PRODUCT/@ITEM')` and an inner loop looking at `$xml->CREATED->CATEGORY->PRODUCT`, but there's nothing to relate these two, so you'll just get every possible combination of those two loops.